# Chrome aw snap from ChromeDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have an integration test suite that uses selenium along with chromedriver.  Within the last week, I have noticed that the aw snap page from chrome has shown up very frequently.  When I switch the chromedriver to firefoxdriver, everything works fine.  What could be the cause of this outbreak of aw snap pages?

I am running with the latest version of Chrome and ChromeDriver:

chrome version 22.0.1229.79 m

chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0

Comment: Tried an older version of chrome & chrome driver? Mainly to try and determine if this is related to a particular version of Chrome.